# Perl - Split sorted array into two arrays based on values

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I am fairly new to Perl.

I have a large array of numbers which is sorted first:

```
my @numbers = do {                                                      
        open my $fh, '<', glob("hotfolder/*.out") or die $!;            
        local $/;                                                           
        <$fh> =~ /\d+/g;                                                    
};

    my @sorted_numbers = sort { $a <=> $b } @numbers;
```

The sorted values are now in the @sorted_numbers array.
Next it needs to find the missing values in this array:

```
my @missing;

     my $i = 0;
            for ( $sorted_numbers[ 0 ] .. $sorted_numbers[ -1 ] ) {         
                ++$i, next if $_ == $sorted_numbers[ $i ];                  
                    push @missing, "$_\n";
    }
```

This is where I need some help. I am not sure how to achieve the next step.
Each number in the array either starts with 2 (200000) or 3 (300000).

The missing values should only show between these ranges.
Let's say the first range finished at 240000. The other range will start somewhere over 300000.

Of course I do not want to return all the values outside these two ranges as missing.

I tried something along these lines but the syntax and logic is completely wrong:

```
    foreach (my $step = @sorted_numbers) {


    if ($step <= 299999) {
        my $i = 0;
            for ( $sorted_numbers[ 0 ] .. $sorted_numbers[ -1 ] ) {         
                ++$i, next if $_ == $sorted_numbers[ $i ];                  
                    push @missing, "$_\n";
                    }   
    }
    else ($step > 299999) {
        my $i = 0;
            for ( $sorted_numbers[ 0 ] .. $sorted_numbers[ -1 ] ) {         
                ++$i, next if $_ == $sorted_numbers[ $i ];                  
                    push @missing2, "$_\n"; 
                    }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if something is unclear and I'll be happy to provide further information.

Comment: Can you supply an illustrative data set (smaller one) along with a desired output? I'm not sure I'm following exactly what you're after. You've indicated problems with the 'next step' but I don't see what the 'next step' actually is.

Comment: Sure. 
For example if this is the range:
269996 269998 269999 301002 301003 301004 301006 301007

This should return as missing only the following two values and ignore the large gap:
269997
301005

Comment: Note: `glob("hotfolder/*.out")` should be `( glob("hotfolder/*.out") )[0]`. The former will give very odd results

Comment: Thank you, I changed it for the latter one. It worked either way, but I am sure the second syntax is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the difference between neighbouring numbers. If it's more than 1 but small enough (see `$gap_size` below), report the missing numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $gap_size = 50;  # Tune this to your needs.

my @numbers = sort { $a <=> $b } map /\d+/g, <>;

for my $i (1 .. $#numbers) {
    my $diff = $numbers[$i] - $numbers[$i-1];
    if ($diff > 1 && $diff < $gap_size) {
        say for $numbers[$i-1] + 1 .. $numbers[$i] - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. 
Where could I put "push @missing"? so that the missing values still get pushed to an array?

Comment: Where the 'say' is. 1